# Is there any way to use SCOPE_IDENTITY if using a multiple insert statement?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, spring.net, scope-identity

I will import many data rows from a csv file into a SQL Server database (through a web application). I need the auto generated id value back for the client.

If I do this in a loop, the performance is very bad (but I can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` without any problems).

A more performant solution would be a way like this:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Is there any way to get all generated IDs and not only the last generated id?

Comment: No, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only gives you the **one, latest** inserted `IDENTITY` value. But you could check out the `OUTPUT` clause of SQL Server ....

Comment: Comment to your deleted answer:  I think you should remove the the first line and change the third line to `sqlBuilder.Append("OUTPUT INSERTED.autoid ");`. No need to put the output in a table variable if you want the output to your client code.

Answer (score 62):

No, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only gives you the **one, latest** inserted `IDENTITY` value. But you could [check out the `OUTPUT` clause of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) ....

```
DECLARE @IdentityTable TABLE (SomeKeyValue INT, NewIdentity INT)

INSERT INTO [MyTable]
OUTPUT Inserted.Keyvalue, Inserted.ID INTO @IdentityTable(SomeKeyValue, NewIdentity)
VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3')
```

Once you've run your `INSERT` statement, the table variable will hold "some key value" (for you, to identify the row) and the newly inserted `ID` values for each row inserted. Now go crazy with this! :-)

Comment: Is there any risk if multiple users work on the same table - can they get wrong ids (of the other users)?

Comment: @ThorstenKraus: no, each transaction gets only their own values back

Comment: Inserted.KeyValue doesnt exist in SQL 2014?

Comment: @DannyRancher: depends - the `Inserted` pseudo table refers to the table you're **inserting into** - in my example, it refers to `MyTable`. So if that table contains a column `Keyvalue`, then it'll be showing that in the `OUTPUT` statement. This has nothing to do with any particular SQL Server version.....

Comment: love this solution